# C# and DotNetBrowser Ajax request do not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dotnetbrowser

I use a DotNetBrowser in my WPF application and I have a problem
js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json").success(function() {
      alert("succes");
  }).error(function(e) { 
      alert("error");
  });
});
```

error

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

how fix??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `--disable-web-security` Chromium switch before creating any Browser or BrowserView instances:

```
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--disable-web-security");
```

The following article provides more details about switches: 
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110017-chromium-switches